# Can I access a Azure FileShare from remote Server just like any other Isilon Share?

Tags: windows, powershell, azure-files, storage-file-share

I have an Azure FileShare which I have mounted as a local Disk in a Server [Doc](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/tips-amp-tricks-for-azure-file-shares/ba-p/277943)

```html
Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                                                                                                                                       CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                                                                                                                                       ---------------
A                   0.00       1024.00 FileSystem    \\xxxxxxxxxx.file.core.windows...
```

Now, I'm able to access the FileShare locally from my Server. But, can I create a Share using my Local new Drive **A:** using **New-SmbGlobalMapping**

```html
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ChildItem A:\
    Directory: A:\
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                                                         
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                                                         
d-----          1/5/2021   3:11 PM                TestFolder
-a----        12/30/2020  12:52 PM           7713 debug123.log                                                                                                                                                                 
-a----        12/31/2020  10:15 AM           7713 temp.log
```

Comment: What do you need, please describe clearly? Your title and your question are not asking the same question, right?

Comment: Hello Jason,
My question is same as the title. Can i access my Mounted Azure File share same way we access Isilon Fileshare? \\ComputerName\AzureFileShare